# Setting and configuring a subversion repository for my .net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn, visual-studio-2008

I am developing a ASP.net project in visual studio.
Every thing was fine when I was the only developer here, but I needed some helping hands to contribute to my project.

Currently there are 4 developers not in a same geographic location.
So after the files are changed and submitted to me, a lot of effort and time is wasted in merging the code.
So I was thinking of creating a subversion of this project.
I have worked with SVN through Tortoise, but I have not done the set up.
Please suggest me a way to set up an SVN.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check this? http://willperone.net/Code/svnserver.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to decide is the hosting space for your code.

- If you are developing an opensource project, then you can go for [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/hosting/) or any other provider. If your project is private, then you can coose any private repository such as [assembla](http://offers.assembla.com/free-subversion-hosting/). If you go in this way, you will get a `checkout` url. You can just commit your project to this url.
- If you are having your own server to host the code, then follow the steps provided in [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html).

Comment: thanks, have up voted your answer, let me go through the articles once.

Comment: In between, I found [this](http://svn-ref.assembla.com/subversion-server-guide-windows.html) helpful. You can have a look at it.

Comment: I think [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) will be a good solution for hosting repository as you have 4 developers which are not in a same geographic location.